# ASP.NET MVC Routing wrong

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I'm having some troubles when trying to use routes in ASP.NET MVC 3.
I'm in this URL:

mysite/InitialPage/123456  <- partner ID

Routing it...

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "InitialPageRoute",
    "InitialPage/{partnerID}",
    new { controller = "InitialPage", action = "Index" }
);
```

OK, it works fine.
When I put a Html.ActionLink to redirect to another page...

```
@Html.ActionLink("Another copy of some bill", "CopyOfBill", "Payment", new { partnerID = ViewBag.PartnerID })
```

And routing this way...

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CopyOfBillRoute",
    "Payment/CopyOfBill/{partnerID}",
    new { controller = "Payment", action = "CopyOfBill" }
);
```

And doesn't work.
Anyone have any idea?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Is the 2nd route ahead of the more generic route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be best to use a `RouteLink` in this case (name the route explicitly), since both the controller and action are hard-coded.

```
@Html.RouteLink("Another copy of some bill", "CopyOfBillRoute", 
    new { partnerID = ViewBag.PartnerID })
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, dbaseman, it's more elegant than Shyju's solution above!

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) overload

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

So your code will be

```
@Html.ActionLink("Another copy of some bill", "CopyOfBill", "Payment",
                                    new { partnerID = ViewBag.PartnerID },null)
```

Assuming you do not want to specify any HTML attributes for the anchor tag. If you want, replace the last parameter (`null`) with the HTML Attributes.

Answer (score 0):

first you write your route in Global.asax at the top . top you make your first route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CopyOfBillRoute",
    "Payment/CopyOfBill/{partnerID}",
    new { controller = "Payment", action = "CopyOfBill" }
);
```

and use your route like this

```
@Html.RouteLink("click", "Regis",new {id=>id.Id})
```

i think this will help you